# How to fix this Java code to upload file with webview element android studio

Tags: java, android, file, upload

Developing very basic app for my site to upload files to server using a webview to emulate the desktop process, failing to get it to work.

I have copied code from GitHub to form this app, however when I press the input button on the HTML form I am prompted to select a file from my phone's storage, after doing so the selected file doesn't show up in the HTML form, and pressing the button again results in no action. I've no idea why and I really don't know Java, can anyone help? (YouTube video of original GitHub poster - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oFGQbXdWv-g) (Github page - https://github.com/tarikul1988/WebViewFileUploadWorking)

The entire project code is as follows;

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.xyz.imagedrop.MainActivity">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview_sample"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</WebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.xyz.imagedrop;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final static int FCR = 1;
    WebView webView;
    private String mCM;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUM;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUMA;

    @SuppressLint({"SetJavaScriptEnabled", "WrongViewCast"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webview_sample);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 &&(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
     }
    assert webView != null;

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        webSettings.setMixedContentMode(0);
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
    webView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
    //webView.loadUrl("https://infeeds.com/");
    webView.loadUrl("http://imagedrop.xyz");

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {

            if (mUMA != null) {
                mUMA.onReceiveValue(null);
            }

            mUMA = filePathCallback;
            // Intent takePictureIntent = new 
Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);


            Intent contentSelectionIntent = new 
Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            contentSelectionIntent.setType("*/*");
//                Intent[] intentArray;
//
//                if (takePictureIntent != null) {
//                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
//                } else {
//                    intentArray = new Intent[0];
//                }

            Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, 
contentSelectionIntent);
            // chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image 
Chooser");
            // chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, 
intentArray);
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);

            return true;
        }
    });
}

public class Callback extends WebViewClient {
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String 
description, String failingUrl) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed loading app!", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.xyz.imagedrop">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"> 
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission  
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you share your code for easy debug.

Comment: I have made the necessary changes